# Cannot close Fragment inside Handler getting IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, handler

I am trying to start fragment and close it after few seconds, but I got the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

The code that produces exception is:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        fragment = new MediaControlFragment();


        manager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.media_control_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
           @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something again
                Log.i(PLAYER_ACTIVITY_TAG, "DESTROYING FRAGMENT");

                manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
                         }
        }, 3500);
```

Now I got the error on line where fragment shoud be removed.

Can anybody help me to achiev this?

EDIT:

LOG:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: PID: 28254
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
at aoc.netcast.rs.android_ott_client.activities.PlayerActivity$1.run(PlayerActivity.java:150)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:769)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: please put complete log and method.

Comment: The method is above, it is executed in **onCreate** method in acitivty.

and the log is added in edit section of question.

Comment: can you please add your complete onCreate method?

Comment: try CommitAllowingStateLoss() instead of commit()

Comment: whole code:
https://pastebin.com/snbxaGct

Answer (score 1):

According to your code : https://pastebin.com/snbxaGct

you are getting this error because you have called HomeActivity by calling

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
```

and then when you are adding or removing fragment from `PlayerActivity` , it will generate error, because you switched to different Activity `HomeActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and this is working fine for me :

```
    final FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    final SomeFragment fragment = new SomeFragment();


    manager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frame, fragment)
            .commit();
//R.id.frame is frame layout.


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do something again
            manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
        }
    }, 3500);
```

Try to use `"CommitAllowingStateLoss()"` instead of `"commit()"`.

Comment: Hi, please can you look at my log that I have added in EDIT section. Don't know y am I running in this exception.

Comment: as from your logs,all i can say is this error is occuring due to this line.`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState 
` Check for any errors in your `onCreate` method

Comment: according to the error this line causes the exception:
`manager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that from a runnable...First get the activity from the fragment by using `getActivity()` and then with the activity do the following

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 //your code here which you want to perform in UI   
                }
            });
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I didn't mentioned, this code has been executed in activity, not in fragment.